# Nuget Package Manager Unresponsive in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I just completed a fresh install of Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

When I run Visual Studio, go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager, and select 1 of the 3 options (Package Manager Console, Manage NuGet Packages for Solution or Package Manager Settings), nothing happens.  The menu closes and no windows appear.

When I go to Options > NuGet Package Manager, I get "An error occurred loading this property page."

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing NuGet Package Manager from Extensions and Updates, but this doesn't solve the problem.  I have also downloaded NuGet.Tools.vsix and when I run this, it tells me that the extension is already installed to all applicable products.

I don't know if I'm missing a setting that enables the Package Manager in Visual Studio, or if this problem is caused by something else...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This turned out to be a permissions issue that I encountered after the VS installation.  I'm not sure if it was a bug in VS or something that is exclusive to my network account settings.

Comment: Could you please give an actual answer about how you solved this? this doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 6):

Un-install  Nuget Package that came with Visual Studio 2015 RTM ( Tools->Extensions and Updates).

Re-install latest (3.1.60 or >) Nuget Package Manager Visual Studio Extension  ( from Online)

Then you can open without errors or silently failing

Comment: Doesn't work. uninstall throw an error `object not set to reference of an object` uninstall a second time actually removed it. Reinstalling pop another error `object not set to reference of an object` and after it says it's already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issues as Sean, I found that updating to the latest version of the package manager (3.1.60724.766 at time of writing) seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yea npm is buggy in 2015 remove dependency check when installing and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem that sean described. Uninstalling NuGet and installing the newest version from the website did not seem to have any effects.

But this way worked for me:
I went to Windows' Control Panel where you can uninstall software. Visual Studio 2015 has a repair option there. I tried it. The repair dialog recommended to update the repair routine first. So I updated, that needed a few minutes. After this I let the repair routine run. It needed something like one and a half hour. And then the problem was away!